# Objectbox-go: deleting model class

Tags: objectbox

Unfortunately, ObjectBox Go's docs provide no information about deletion of entire type structure "powered" by ObjectBox.

Let's say we have a struct

```
//go:generate go run github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/cmd/objectbox-gogen

type Test struct {
    Id            uint64
    Name          string
}
```

After some time, I decide remove entire Test from the project (deleted test.go and test.obx.go). Unfortunately, go generate still "remembers" this phantom class and keeps adding it to objectbox-model.go

```
model.RegisterBinding(TestBinding)
```

How can I safely delete this struct (and its data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the ObjectBox code generator doesn't delete entities because it works with partial input information (a single file at a time) and therefore it doesn't know whether you have removed an entity or it will be in the next file the generator is called for.

I've created a follow-up issue/feature request on GH: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-generator/issues/22

If you really needed to remove the entity NOW, until the removal feature is added to the generator: the current workaround, would be to manually update the `objectbox-model.json`, removing the entity JSON code block defining it and adding its `uid` to the `retiredEntityUids` list to avoid reuse of the same UID (which would break things). Additionally, the same has to be done for the removed properties, indexes, and relations (each has its `retired*Uids` list). After the generator is re-run, the entity would be removed from the `objectbox-model.go`.

**I don't recommend doing this as it's easy to make an error when manually editing the model JSON file, potentially causing a loss of data.** If you can, wait for the generator to support the removal.